# В чем причина ошибки "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length"?

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь создать функцию merge(), которая принимает на вход два отсортированных массива и результатом выполнения функции должен быть единственный отсортированный массив. Например

merge([2,4,7,8], [1,3,5,6]) => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], но как результат получаю выше упомянутую ошибку.
Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    let arr = []

    while(arr1[0] !== undefined || arr2[0] !== undefined) {
        if(arr1[0] < arr2[0]) {
            arr.push(arr1.shift())
        } else {
            arr.push(arr2.shift())
        }
    }

    if(arr1.length > 0) {
        arr.concat(arr1)
    } else {
        arr.concat(arr2)
    }

    return arr
}
```

Буду очень рад, если объясните мою ошибку)))

Comment: Заменить || на &&

Comment: А ещё лучше бы заменить проверку на равенство undefined на проверку длины массива

Comment: Ошибка в том, что первый массив еще не кончился, а второй закончился, из-за получается вечный цикл, подробнее описал в ответе)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в том, что когда доходим до состояния

`arr1 = (2) [7, 8], arr2 = []`

Заходим в цикл, так как один из массивов не пустой

дальше идет сравнение

`if(arr1[0] < arr2[0])`

идем по пути `false`. Где пытается сделать `shift()` от пустого массива, получаем `udefined`.

По сути цикл становится вечным, до тех пор пока движок JS-а не выдаст ошибку.

Как вариант, можно переписать решение задачи так:

```js
const array1 = [2, 4, 7, 8];
const array2 = [1, 3, 5, 6];

function merge(arr1, arr2) {
  let arr = [];

  while (arr1.length || arr2.length) {
    if (arr1.length && arr2.length) {
      const item = arr1[0] < arr2[0] ? arr1.shift() : arr2.shift();
      arr.push(item);
    } else {
      const items = arr1.length && !arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
      arr.push(...items);
      break;
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(merge(array1, array2));
```